Find the probability that there are no collisions among $k<n$ hash digests.
Suppose that we are given $k$ distinct random bit strings (the length does not matter). Consider a hash function $H : \{0,1\}^{*} \rightarrow \{0,1,...,n-1\}$.
I want to find 1) the probability that $k=2$ strings have the same hash digest, and 2) the probability that there are no collisions among the $k < n$ hash digests.
I believe that I have correctly solved 1). I am not certain that my answer for 2) is correct and would like to receive feedback.


the probability that $k=2$ strings have the same hash digest

The first bit string can take $n$ values. If we want no collision, then the second bitstring can take $n - 1$ values. Thus, according to the multiplicative principle of counting we obtain
$$
p[no\_collision]=\frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{n} = \frac{n - 1}{n}, 
$$
which means that
$$
p[collision] = 1 - p[no\_collision] = 1 - \frac{n - 1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$

the probability that there are no collisions among the $k < n$ hash digests.

Similar as before, the first bit string can take $n$ values, the second $n-1$ values, ..., the $k$th $n - (k - 1)$ values. So,
$$
p[no\_collision] = \prod_{i=0}^{k - 1} \frac{n-i}{n},
$$
which I believe can be rewritten to
$$
p[no\_collision] = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \cdot n^k}.
$$

I agree with your analysis.
